# ESP 32 POST request passes an empty body

Tags: express, esp32

So I was using an ESP 32 connected over to a wifi, and I wanted it to access a webpage, which I am serving with nodejs and express.js. I make the post request in the ESP module with http.POST("Hello, World") and in the server, you can see I have setup a little program that console.logs the request. Though the body is always empty. Do you know why? Thank you

ESP 32:

```
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
int httpResponseCode = http.POST("Hello, World!");
```

SERVER:

```
app.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body))
})
```

Comment: Please show more of the ESP32 code, in particular the entire lifecycle of the `http` instance.